# Direct proof of Universal Set [discrete mathematics]

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, proof-explanation

So I've come across this interesting proof question in my discrete mathematics textbook that I'm trying to solve for practice but unfortunately it does not have a solution. Any help with a reasonable solution and explanation so that I can verify my work would be greatly appreciated:

> Suppose that $U$ is the universal set, and that $A$ and $B$ are two
>   arbitrary sets of elements of $U$:
>
> a. First, suppose that $A$ contains at least two elements. Using a
>   direct proof, show that if every proper subset of $A$ is a subset of
>   $B$, then $A$ is a subset of $B$.
>
> b. Give an example that shows that the implication from part (a) is
>   False if $A$ contains only one element.

Comment: For the first one, just assume $A=\{p,q\};p\ne q$. Given $\{p\},\{q\}\subseteq B\implies p,q\in B\implies A\subseteq B$. For the second, note that the only proper subset of a singleton set is the null set, which is a subset of every set $B$. You can substantiate using $A=\{1\},B=\{2\}$.

Comment: Also, welcome to the website. You are advised to include some of your work and attempts at solving the problem, otherwise your post might get downvoted or closed.